# Metal rust with soil

Tags: vegetables, rust

We have raised iron beds in our organic community garden. They are going slightly rusty, will this be OK for the plants?

Comment: Hi Linda, what is a raised iron bed?  Can you provide a picture and tell us about the soil?  Acid or alkaline?

Answer (score 1):

Iron compounds are very common in soils, usually some form of oxide. Red soils are normally the result of iron . So I can't think of a reason it could be a problem for plants. I sometime add cast iron exercise weights to the bottom of a pot to help keep a top-heavy plant upright.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't be a problem - iron oxide isn't water soluble, so is unavailable to plant roots, meaning they won't take it up. This link https://homeguides.sfgate.com/can-rust-planter-harm-herbs-97056.html, whilst it refers to herb growing, might be of interest.